# Gradle: How to run custom task after an Android Library is built?

Tags: android, gradle, build

I have an Android Library, it's generating a debug.aar and a release.aar, I need to copy the release.aar to another folder as a reference to other part of the project.

What I've done now is in this Android Library build.gradle I defined a task:

```
task copyAARToCommonLibs(type: Copy) {
    from('../build/outputs/aar') {
        include '*-release.arr'
    }
    into '../SomeSampleApps/libs'
}
```

I'm trying to run this task after the arr is generated, which I assume is assembleRelease stage, so I tried do this in this build.gradle

```
assembleRelease.doLast{
   copyAARToCommonLibs
}
```

I build the overall project using

```
 gradle build
```

But this task is running at the very beginning of the whole process.

I also tried this:

```
 applicationVariants.all { variant ->
     variant.assemble.doLast {
         copyAARToCommonLibs
     }
 }
```

inside android{} property(I guess that's what it's called?)
Running gradle build, got this error: Could not find property 'applicationVariants'

I then came across this snippet:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) { compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn copyAARToCommonLibs }
```

But it seems this makes the task to run after compiling, I don't know exactly how to modify this to run after assemble.

Could someone please correct me where I did wrong and how can I get this copy task work after the .arr file is generated?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It seems that `finalizedBy` might be helpful.

```
assembleRelease.finalizedBy(copyAARToCommonLibs)
```

Mind the fact that in the following way you won't define a dependency:

```
assembleRelease.doLast {
   copyAARToCommonLibs
}
```

actually.. it does exactly nothing. You need to execute the task:

```
assembleRelease.doLast {
   copyAARToCommonLibs.execute()
}
```

but running task in the following way is discouraged and very bad practice.

You can also try:

```
assembleRelease.doLast {
   copy {
      from('../build/outputs/aar') {
        include '*-release.aar'
      }
      into '../AscendonSDKSamples/libs'
   }
}
```

Comment: Both `finalizedBy` and `doLast { task detail }` work for me, thank you so much!

Comment: Just to prevent someone from getting inexplicable errors, there is a small typo in `include '*-release.arr'`, which should obviously be:
`include '*-release.aar`

Comment: I get an error: `access to finalizedBy exceeds its access rights`

Comment: When I try this, I get the following:     **Could not get unknown property 'assembleRelease' for project 'LibraryProjectName' of type org.gradle.api.Project.**. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @AnkitMittal Wrap it in afterEvaluate eg  ... 
afterEvaluate {
    assembleRelease.finalizedBy {
        copyaarfile
    }
}

Answer (score 7):

I went with finalizedBy() but had to include it within an afterEvaluate...

```
afterEvaluate {
    if (gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains(":app:assembleFatReleaseInternal")) {
        play.enabled = true
        play.commit = true
        play.track = "internal"
        play.releaseStatus = "completed"
        play.releaseName = versionName

        generateFatReleaseInternalBuildConfig.dependsOn set_build_date
        assembleFatReleaseInternal.finalizedBy(uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileFatReleaseInternal)
        uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileFatReleaseInternal.finalizedBy(publishFatReleaseInternal)
    }
}
```

This worked well for automating the upload of native symbols to Fabric / Crashlytics and other things such as automated play store publishing.

Comment: This addition of `afterEvaluate` is essential. But I think that usually you will have both **assembleFatDebug** and **assembleFatRelease** defined, so `else` may be wrong here. Only one of the **assemble** tasks will eventually be invoked because you choose the build configuration. The other one is either disabled or dormant.

Comment: good call... taking a look at some of my existing Gradle scripts I am using gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains().

Answer (score 4):

Because android studio add task by dynamic,so `assembleRelease` will not be recognized.
Just add hook after task added event happens.

```
    tasks.whenTaskAdded {
        theTask ->
            if (theTask.name.contains('externalNativeBuild')) {
                theTask.doLast{
                    println "[*] begin to copy file."
                }
            }
//            println theTask.name
    }
```